# Corollary of Monotone Convergence Theorem

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(g_n)$ be a sequence in $M^+$, then

$\int \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty g_n\right)d\mu=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\int g_nd\mu \right)$

proof: Let $f_n=g_1+\cdots+g_n$, then $f_n$ is a monotone increasing sequence of functions in $M^+$. I wan t use Monotone Convergence Theorem but I don't know how to guarantee that $f_n$ converges to $f=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n g_n=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}g_n$.

Comment: What does the word "entonces" mean? I don't think that it is English.

Comment: @Byron Schmuland. It is Spanish for "then".

Comment: @user254665 Thanks. You learn something new every day.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland. I just googled it.I didn't know either.

Answer (score 1):

Your $(f_n)$ is an increasing sequence in $M^+$ and, by definition, it converges to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g_n$ in the pointwise sense. Also, it is obviously bounded above by $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g_n$. Note that:

- Pointwise convergence means that for each concrete $x$, $f_n(x) \to \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g_n(x)$
- It may happen that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g_n(x) = +\infty$ for some $x$, but this still means that $f_n(x)$ converges to $+\infty$